# Is there a way to have a map with complex keys in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I want to implement a map with two-part keys in typescript. My key format is like this:

```
type Key = {
  section: number,
  index: number
}
```

I have tried to create a map like this:

```
let map = new Map<Key,Record>()
```

But whenever I try to get a value from the map:

```
cont val = map.get(myKey)
```

The value is `undefined`.

Is there any way to have a map in typescript with complex types?

Comment: Is the object stored in `myKey` the same reference as the one that you used when setting the key-value pair in your Map?

Comment: `let map = new Map<Key,Record>()` Is not valid TS code.
Did you mean `let map = new Map<Key, Record<string, any>>()`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an object as a key of `Map` you need to make sure the **reference** key that you have used to set the map, is the same when you want to get from the map!

```
let myKey:Key = {index:1,section:2}
map.set(myKey,your object)
const val = map.get(myKey); // Now has value
```

But I suggest you to use primitive type as a key. So you can append `section` and `index` as new string key!

Comment: [Wrong](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQN4CgpQM4QMbAEsB7AOwC4oSBXAWwCMIAnDKAkgEwgA8Lr6m0AXzRoANhGBQaAQzBJKEAO5QAsrIA8cEABooAJTxFG7dVmCM2Ac13SSIAHz2AFAEoRaXKTNRp8mWAA6SwknFFYObgoAFgAmXRx8YnIoWKhBFyA). No need to set the key. See type of `a`.

Comment: @Heniker type of `a` is `Record<string, any> | undefined` and it was expected. what is wrong?

Comment: There is no need to explicitly set the type. References also work without explicit type.

Comment: @Heniker I mean if you use an object for key of  `Map` it looks at reference of object instead of value.
`Set the map`  means use the `set` methods of map--> `map.set(myKey,your object)`

Comment: @sak You can use primitive type by appending your property into one string key